# NSTable view DataSource and Delegate Stopped working after update to Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, macos

One upon a time I wrote app in early version of Swift (2016). After update to Swift 4.1 drag and drop for reordering rows stopped to work.
I changed delegate functions names but they're never called. Delegate itself is inited.

```
class DragableOrderedSetTableViewDelegate: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrayController:NSArrayController!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        ...... 
        //this is called
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
                   writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet,
                   to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {

        Swift.print("write rows to")

        **never called**

        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
                   validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
                   proposedRow row: Int,
                   proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> NSDragOperation {
        Swift.print("validate drop")

        **never called**

        return []

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
                   acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo,
                   row: Int,
                   dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
        Swift.print("accept drop")
        **never called**
        return true
    }
}
```

NSTableView delegate an dataSource is connected to this object.

Where could be a mistake?

Comment: Add `@objc` to those methods (this must have been answered somewhere).

Comment: I didn't help :( I added @objc to class and functions. Still silence.

Comment: @objc func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,
                       writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet,
                       to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool

Comment: Then I don't know :(

Comment: :) Mee too. Still.